# codeigniter using ion auth, need to make input text fields longer

Tags: codeigniter

just installed ion auth for codeigniter and im customizing the login page.

the default login.php uses:

```
<?php echo lang('login_password_label', 'password');?>
<?php echo form_input($password);?>
```

which produces the following html results;

```
<label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password"  />
```

i need to append **size="55"** to the input box, so it looks like this:

```
<label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" size="55" name="password" value="" id="password"  />
```

any ideas how i would do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$password = array(
              'name'        => 'password',
              'id'          => 'password',
              'size'        => '55',
            );

echo form_password($password);
```

Comment: thanks for that info, worked perfectly! I saw that in the user guide but i thought it applied to regular values and not html or css values.